# Not able to clear my setInterval in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I have an IONIC 4 application where I need to call an api every 20 seconds and if the user moves to other page need to stop calling that api. I am able to make the api call at every 20 seconds but not able to stop it when I move to some other page. Here is my code below, may I know where I went wrong?

```
 rateTimer:any;

constructor(private loginServiceService: LoginServiceService) {
    this.loginServiceService.getappData();

    this.rateTimer=setInterval(() => { 
      this.loginServiceService.getappData(); 
   }, 10000);
   }

// When I move to other page, I clear the setInterval from here

 ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.rateTimer);
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure ngOnDestroy is called ? In ionic you should use Ionic Page Lifecyle https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

Comment: Yes ngOnDestroy is called, I do get hit there

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Ionic has a cache for page-navigation which is why `ngOnDestroy/ngOnInit` will not always work. However, there's `ionViewDidLeave` which should definitely fire, once the current page is moved away from (see https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router-outlet#life-cycle-hooks for more details):

```
export class YourComponent {
  ionViewDidLeave() {
    // Do actions here
  }
}
```

Comment: So if you console.log() inside `ionViewDidLeave` you see nothing or is it just that the interval does not get cleared?

Comment: The thing is when I use ionViewDidLeave I dont get there but when I use ngOnDestroy I do get the debugger hit there. The issue here is I am getting the hit inside occasionally and not everytim

Comment: why am I not getting hit on ionViewDidLeave ? Any clue

Comment: Weird, honestly I don't know - maybe you find some helpful info in this arcticle: https://medium.com/@paulstelzer/ionic-4-and-the-lifecycle-hooks-4fe9eabb2864#8fe1